# How to factory reset Honda Jazz (Gen 3 / 2015–2020) infotainment system?

Tags: honda, jazz, infotainment

### Context

I have a Honda Jazz 3rd Gen (2016). For a couple weeks, the infotainment system won't fully start. Indeed, it keeps looping on this sequence:

- Honda logo (15s)
- Honda logo + spinning wheel (ca. 60s?)
- blank screen (2s)

It all looks like a software issue to me. I have tried to disconnect the battery for a few seconds, but this had no effect. I've also tried to push radio's on/off button for 20s+, without success.

### Question

How to factory-reset the infotainment system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was similar to the one described in [this forum thread](https://honda-tech.com/forums/honda-civic-2006-2015-79/infotainment-boot-loop-3349011/)… and the solution as well!

I had to simultaneously press for a while (ca. 30s) on both the power and the brightness-level buttons, as indicated below.

[image: Honda Jazz audio/information system and where to press]

The system then reboot, and asked me to press the power button for 2 seconds (anti-theft program)… and it was then all good!

<sub><sup>*Kudos to [jazzaro](https://clubjazz.org/forum/index.php?topic=12719.msg92545#msg92545) who found the relevant link.*</sup></sub>